# Apache24u / phpinfo: still showing old version

Tags: php, apache-2.4, php-fpm, httpd, httpd.conf

Ive upgraded the server from default `apache 2.4.6` to the `apache24u` (https://centos.pkgs.org/7/ius-x86_64/httpd24u-2.4.34-1.ius.centos7.x86_64.rpm.html).

when I check it via shell, I get the correct versions:
[image]

However, phpinfo is showing wrong version:
[image]

php is running via `php-fpm` btw. `php` is installed via remi and apache via IUS.

ive restarted apachectl, httpd and php-fpm buts till old version. any idea plz? Thanks.

Comment: Your browser's cache?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself after burning a lot of brain.. There were running `httpd` as well as `php-fpm` processes that didnt stop even after `$> systemctl stop ****`.

So I had to `pgrep` and kill them manually. Then I restarted httpd and php-fpm and it solved it.